# How to hardcode group information on field for cascading validation

Tags: java, spring, validation

I have the following bean;

```
public class Customer {

    @NotNull(groups = New.class)
    private String id;

    @Valid
    private List<CustomerDetail> detailList;
}
```

As you see, I cascade validation down to each `CustomerDetail` in `detailList` by annotating the field with `@Valid`, but I wish to propagate the validation with a hard-coded group, is that possible? Whatever group is supplied for validation, I wish a fixed group, namely `New` to be active in validation of `detailList`.

This is due to my conflicting requirements, one wishes to treat details as a sub-resource of `Customer` therefore I need full validation on it all the time when it is validated within a customer pojo. Another requirement is to treat each detail as a separate resource, therefore I need to do patch for some fields, so when it is validated separately, different groups can be applied.

```
public class CustomerDetail {

    @NotNull(groups = New.class)
    private String desc;

    private String remark;
}
```

So when it is any sort of operation for `Customer`, every `CustomerDetail` in `customerList` should use `New` group, even if `Customer` does not necessarily use that group for validation.

In a way, I want to do this;

```
public class Customer {

    @NotNull(groups = New.class)
    private String id;

    @Validated(New.class)
    private List<CustomerDetail> detailList;
}
```

But I was unable to find such a feature, I wanted to do this to evade creating multiple groups, which was deemed confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to introduce your own annotation to have class level constraints. Create a custom annotation with own validation logic implemented in the validator.

See the chapter 6.2. Class-level constraints of [the doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html)

Or see [the example](http://www.summa.com/blog/2013/05/30/creating-custom-validation-constraints)